# Value of density of state effective mass and transport effective mass to calculate conductivity

Tags: condensed-matter, physical-properties-of-materials, transport

How can density of state effective mass and transport effective mass can be defined to calculate conductivity for a cubic system with parabolic but anisotropic dispersion relation? What will be the value of both for $\ce{Mg2Si}$?

Comment: Are you asking what the concept of effective mass *means* for an anisotropic system, or how you can calculate it?

Comment: Yes what is the concept of both effective mass i.e denstity of state effective mass and transport effective mass for anisotropic system with respect to conductivity means how can conductivity be calculated using effective mass for anisotropic system ?

Comment: Shalini, unfortunately Phil may not have seen your answer to his question, and your follow-up question to him, because you need to ping users with the @ symbol in order for them to receive a notification. @PhilHasnip pinging you now!

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks for info , I want to close this question Could you please close this ?

Comment: @Shalini Thanks for the ping!  In an anisotropic system the effective mass is a 3x3 rank-2 tensor, not a scalar. 

Consider Newton's law "F=ma", which says that the vector F and the vector a are linearly related. The general linear relationship is when m is represented by a matrix. (This means that the force and acceleration are not necessarily parallel.)

Comment: I’m closing this question because OP requested it